# How to change select value if it's generated using what I assume is bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I have a select drop down that I can't wrap my head around how to change it using a script.

```
<select name="DataTables_Table_0_length" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" class="form-control input-sm">
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="50">50</option>
  <option value="-1">All</option>
</select>
```

By default it loads the option for 20, but I'd like to edit it to load -1(All).

What I've Tried:

```
var select = document.getElementById('DataTables_Table_0_length').children[0].children[0];
console.log(select.value);
setTimeout(console.log(select.value),6000);
console.log(select);
```

For logging purposes, I tried to see if the value even changed, but it does not. It only does what I want if i manually click on the value on the page.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify: you are wanting the initial option to be shown in the drop-down to be "All"?

Place the `selected` attribute on the `<option>` element you want to show. By default, the element that shows is going to be the first one in the list.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#attr-selected

```
<select name="DataTables_Table_0_length" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" class="form-control input-sm">
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="-1" selected>All</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I want the page to change to the All option after the page loads. I'm scraping + adding HTML to this website, so I can't edit HTML like that.

Comment: Can you try 

`THEOPTIONELEMENTOFINTEREST.setAttribute('selected', true)`

Comment: that is to say, you can add the selected attribute with JavaScript:


```var options = document.querySelectorAll('option');

options[2].setAttribute('selected', true);```

Comment: trying this now, give me a second

Comment: without the code, none of option tags have the attribute select="true", adding your suggestion does add it, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Try checking out this working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/07pmag3u/

Are you getting any errors? What do you mean by "it doesn't do anything"? Keep in mind if you have any additional `<option>` elements on the page, this will not work, as it works under the assumption that there are only the `<option>` elements in this snippet.

Comment: yeah i'm aware, these are the only options on the page I'm using.
https://imgur.com/gallery/ie8Uo this shows you what happens, and what should happen

Comment: I took a look at your screenshots. Is there some function that is doing the showing of your items that is maybe not being triggered by the change of the `<select>` element that you are trying to manipulate?

Comment: I did some digging, basically it calls a function from an outside javascript file. If it helps, I used Visual Event to see what the trigger event was and the function, but I have no idea how to implement this in my javascript code
https://imgur.com/a/3QOoL

Comment: My hunch is that, although my code snippet changes the selected `<option>` of the `<select>`element, the change to only show a certain number of items is not being triggered. You probably have to figure out what the function name is so you can call it from your JavaScript.
This is challenging because the file you referenced is minified. I would look for an un-minified version of the file to try and find the function you need and call it.

Answer (score 0):

1) First of all you are selecting by id, but your select only has  a name attribute
2) Try this after adding the id tag:

```
var select = document.getElementById('DataTables_Table_0_length');
console.log(select.value);
select.value=-1;
setTimeout(console.log(select.value),6000);
console.log(select);
```

Comment: the select is in a label which is in a DIV with that class id, hence the .children[0].children[0]. I also tried what you did originally (it's inside the setTimeout part, and yes that works but it doesn't do anything. the only way for the function to happen is if I click on it myself like I stated above.